# Python - Oracle : cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist even while it is existing

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to access an Oracle database table using a python script. The aim is to read data from DB1

i.e read from DB1.Table1 and load the data into the Home DB i.e
into DB2.Table2. Table 1 and table 2 have same structure.

Volume of Table 1 is 55 million and the script runs successfully for ~100 records and after that it gives the below error. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
SELECT PART:
base_qry = 'SELECT * FROM %s'%(src_tbl)
cur.execute(base_qry)
base_data = cur.fetchmany(1000)

INSERT PART:
it = 0
n_tuples = len(data_lst)
while it < n_tuples:
    try:
        subset_lst = []
        subset_lst = data_lst[it: it + 10000]
        cur.close()
        cur = DEVcon.cursor()
        cur.executemany(ins_qry, subset_lst)

        if is_commit == "Y":
            DEVcon.commit()
        it += 10000
```

Comment: Well, you never reveal what your ins_qry is. Answer to your question is in this query it seems.

Comment: @hamilyon : The query is created dynamically during run time.  This particular error is coming for the table with 500 columns..

Comment: @hamilyon : INSERT INTO USER.TABLENAME VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22,:23,:24,:25,:26,:27,:28,:29,:30,:31,:32,:33,:34,:35,:36,:37,:38,:39,:40,:41,:42,:43,:44,:45,:46,:47,:48,:49,:50,:51,:52,:53,:54,:55,:56,:57,:58,:59..................,:483,:484,:485,:486,:487,:488,:489,:490,:491,:492,:493,:494,:495,:496,:497,:498,:499)"

Comment: What does this query return when you run it manually? The error should be obvious by now

Answer (score 0):

For those might think if your Code might have error while working on Oracle DB; If you get any ORA-00XXX error, not just in python in any language/library/technology, that means it is all about Oracle DB. Don't blame your code :)

Table does not exists could mean 2 things. First, there is really no such a table or view exists. Both SELECT or INSERT queries could throw this error. If you are certain about table's existence then be sure about you are looking at correct DB. You might be checking for different DB than your code does.

Second, if you are trying to access another SCHEMA's table you might not have insert  privilege. You have to run below DCL command in order to insert any data to table.

```
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_TO_INSERT TO YOUR_APP_USERNAME
```

If you are using INSERT INTO with SELECT statement then you have to have select privileges **ALL** other SCHEMA's table that in query. There is no need any GRANT for current user's tables. Be sure about using SELECT queries like SCHEMA.TABLE, if there are any PUBLIC SYNONYMS you might try to read from irrelevant table.

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_IN_YOUR_SELECT TO YOUR_APP_USERNAME
```

Again you should check which USER you are connecting to DB in order to use these privileges correctly. You might be using the one that don't have privileges.

Happy Coding.